# What is this cactus and how should I take care for it?

Tags: identification, cactus

I received my cactus as a gift approximately 10 years ago. I have never known what species of cactus it is and I thought it is time to figure it out.

I am unfamiliar with cactus and I don't know if the shape of the one I have is characteristic to it's species or is mine simply odd looking. I have been browsing cactus pictures on google, looking for tall cactus with somewhat narrow base and fattening up from there. Mine looks like a bat or club to me. It has never had flowers, fruits, or offspring, which really confuses me.

There is nothing specific I know about conditions my cactus likes, like when a bigger pot is needed, what temperature range is optimal. Etc.

This is how it looks, height is 59 cm (1.93 feet):
[image: image: unknown cactus]
[image: image: unknown cactus]
[image: image: unknown cactus]
[image: image: unknown cactus]

The closest looking picture I have found so far is of Peruvian Apple cactus. But mine is darker, has narrower base, and grows alone. Species are related, I guess.

[image: image: Peruvian Apple cactus]

Comment: There are a few with this growth habit, but need better pics or more info - how many ribs around the plant, so maybe a photo taken from the top looking down, and preferably a photo not against that green background, its quite hard to pick out detail of spines. What's at the top also helps with ID - looks like the spines are yellowish brown? And quite long...

Comment: @Bamboo Thanks. I added 2 more photos, one is a top-down look, in the other one cactus is against a white background.
6 ribs. Spines are yellowish and like half of them darken towards the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its more likely to be Cereus peruvianus, possibly monstruosos, rather than than Cereus repandus (Peruvian Apple Cactus), and it grows to 2-3 feet over time.

Care instructions for these are the same anyway, as with most cacti - likes average warmth from spring to autumn, but keep cool in winter, (50 to 55 deg F is ideal). Give it the sunniest spot available, particularly in winter, but if on a windowsill, not above a radiator, and don't leave it on the windowsill on cold nights.

Increase watering in spring, and in the late spring to late summer period, treat as an ordinary houseplant by watering thoroughly when the compost begins to dry out - but don't leave it standing in water. Using tepid water is best - after mid autumn, keep almost dry, just enough water to prevent shrivelling.

When its hot in summer, open the windows - they like fresh air moving around them then. Repot only when essential (when the roots fill the pot) using a pot only slightly larger than the original one. Feed when its actively growing, usually late spring through summer, with either houseplant food or a specialist cactus food, about once every 3-4 weeks.

Comment: Cereus peruvians and Cereus rapandus are synonyms; different names for the same plant, Cereus rapandus is the accepted species name, though peruvianus is more commonly used. This plant is not monstrose. They also grow up to 10 meters, 2-3 feet is only a baby.